# Is it possible to specify position on screen when making a new plot window?

Tags: r

I'd like to specify the position when I create a new plot window. I know `dev.new()` can make a new window with given size. However, is there also a way to specify the location of the newly created window? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is surely platform-dependent. Which OS do you use? (`X11` has `xpos`/`ypos` arguments. Maybe `xpos`/`ypos` will work on Windows/Mac, too?!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sgibb points out, this works on Windows and in `X11` environments.

```
dev.new(xpos=1000,ypos=100)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for Mac because R uses Quartz on Mac rather than X11. It'd be nice to find out the equivalence of xpos/ypos for Quartz.